# Turn a mutable.HashMap[ArrayBuffer[Int]] into immutable.HashMap[Vector] in class constructor

Tags: class, scala, graph, constructor

I am trying to get a `mutable.HashMap[Int, ArrayBuffer[Int]]` into a `immutable.HashMap[Int, Vector]` for part of my class constructor. The result `immutable.HashMap` should be assigned to a `val` as well. What I am doing is reading an edgelist file into a graph format, and once that is done I want to guarentee the graph to be immutable, hence the `immutable.HashMap`.

The constructor should take a `filename: String`, read in the edgelist to some mutable form, and then at the end have a member of the class `val adjList` be the resulting immutable adjacency list form.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
xs.mapValues(v => Vector() ++ v).toMap
```

will do the trick (where xs is your mutable HashMap, of course).